# Add custom buttons to the header navigation per view in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, core-ui

Im my VueJS project, I wanted to add custom buttons to the sub navigation menu. The list of buttons should be definable per view. My first try was to add a simple property to the main data element, but that didn't work. Than I found the concept of mixins, but that doesn't work either. Here's my concept:

```js
// main.js
new Vue({
    //...
    mixins: [{
        data() {
            return {
                customHeaderButtons: [],
                test: '123'
            };
        }
    }],
})
```

```html
<!-- TheHeader.vue -->
<template>
    <CHeader>
        <CSubheader class="px-3">
            <CBreadcrumbRouter class="border-0" />
            <CHeaderNav v-if="$root.customHeaderButtons" class="ml-auto" style="min-height: 0">
                <CHeaderNavLink v-for="item in $root.customHeaderButtons">
                    <CIcon :name="item.iconName" />
                </CHeaderNavLink>
                {{$root.customHeaderButtons}}
            </CHeaderNav>
            {{$root.test}} --> 123
        </CSubheader>
    </CHeader>
</template>

<!-- MyView.vue -->
<template>
    {{test}} --> ABC
</template>
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            customHeaderButtons: [{
                iconName: 'cil-save'
            }],
            test: 'ABC'
        }
    },
    // ...
}
</script>
```

Can you tell me, why the value change from `MyView.vue` isn't applied to the header? In my imagination, as soon as the user navigates to `MyView.vue`, the text in the header bar should toggle to ABC.

PS: TheHeader is part of my template. It is not contained within the view itself!

```html
<!-- TheContainer.vue -->
<template>
  <div class="c-app">
    <TheSidebar/>
    <div class="c-wrapper">
      <TheHeader/> <-- The data from any child view should be sent here <---+
      <div class="c-body">                                                  |
        <main class="c-main">                                               |
          <CContainer fluid>                                                |
            <transition name="fade">                                        |   
              <router-view></router-view> <-- This is where MyView goes ----+
            </transition>
          </CContainer>
        </main>
      </div>
      <TheFooter/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution [inspired by this tutorial](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2019/06/05/triggering-events-router-vue/) now. But I have to admit, that it's complicated and that this is probably not the ideal soultion. Here's how it works:

First up, modify the container vuew (where you have placed your `<router-view>` tag: Add a property binding to your header element/component (as Boussadjra described). Then, add an event listener to the `router-view`, just like that:

```html
<template>
    <div class="c-app">
        <TheSidebar />
        <div class="c-wrapper">
            <TheHeader :customHeaderButtons="customHeaderButtons" />
            <div class="c-body">
                <main class="c-main">
                    <CContainer fluid>
                        <transition name="fade">
                            <router-view @setCustomHeaderButtons="setButtons"></router-view>
                        </transition>
                    </CContainer>
                </main>
            </div>
            <TheFooter />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

In the javascript part of your code, you have to implement that event listener *and* you have to make sure, that you reset the buttons after each page change:

```js
export default {
    name: 'TheContainer',
    components: {
        TheSidebar,
        TheHeader,
        TheFooter
    },
    data() {
        return {
            customHeaderButtons: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        setButtons(buttons) {
            this.customHeaderButtons = buttons;
        }
    },
    beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
        this.customHeaderButtons = [];
        next();
    }
}
```

Now, in your view, you have to emit this event in the `created` event:

```js
export default {
   data() {
       return {
           customHeaderButtons: [{
               iconName: 'cil-save'
           }],
       }
   },
    created() {
        this.$emit('setCustomHeaderButtons', this.customHeaderButtons);
    }
}
```

Make sure, that you define `this.customHeaderButtons` in your view model beforehand.

Also make sure, that you have to re-emit the event in cases where you nest multiple views into each other. It doesn't bubble up automatically! Alternatively, you could use `this.$parent.$emit()` to bypass a nesting level.

If you have better, more simple approaches, feel free to post them.